# What’s the simplest way to switch between 2 analog signals when one of them goes above a specific voltage?

Tags: analog

I need to connect 2 analog signals to the same output, one signal at a time. One of the signals goes through a potentiometer and sits between 0.3V-5V. What is the simplest way to switch that analog signal to the output when it goes above 0.3V? The other signal is generated by DAC and can sit at 0V when needed. The potentiometer voltage needs priority to the output.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I initially read this as switching between two analog signals when one signal exceeded 0.3 V peak-to-peak, but I'm not sure what the potentiometer is doing? In one place, you write that the signal "sits between 0.3 V and 5 V" but then in the next sentence you write "when it goes above 0.3 V." Isn't it always above 0.3 V? Can you please edit your question to clearly describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Quick suggestion use a comparator. If that does not work posting a schematic would be a big help.

Comment: If one signal comes from a DAC then ultimately, it's likely produced digitally by an MCU hence, read the pot voltage by the MCU and output a signal via another (or even the same) DAC that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For analog channel selecting, you can use SN74LV4051 like multiplexer.

To switch to the specific channel when a specific condition occurs, you'll need to use a comparator and reference voltage.
Use some reference voltage source like REF3025 (2.5V) or REF3033 (3.3V), divide it using precision resistors to get 0.3V.
Then you can get logic level triggering signal to switch multiplexcer channel.

(EDIT, the Y0 and Y1 should be swapped in the picture. Potentio -> Y1, DAC -> Y0. Just realised it after posting the picture.)

[image: multiplexing analog at a specific threshold]